# Service composition in Serverless framework and serverless nested stacks discussion

Tags: microservices, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am looking for a decent tooling/way to achieve this for my Microservices defined using Serverless framework:

Define dependencies between services so service will be deployed after the downstream services are deployed

Forex

If 10 microservices have serviceA as a downstream service then serviceA will be deployed first (once) and then the rest of the 10 microservices.

I am looking at https://github.com/aditmalik-synechron/serverless-nested-stack . Should it address the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this plugin, review it to deploy logically.

[serverless-plugin-split-stacks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-split-stacks)